# Deep copying maps in Golang

Tags: json, go, maps, deep-copy

From what I understand, maps are reference types in Go. So assignment will do shallow copy. I plan to do a recursive deep copy of Maps in golang. Recursive because I am dealing with a map that holds the unmarshalled contents of a JSON.

```
func deepCopyJSON(src map[string]interface{}, dest *map[string]interface{}) error {
    if src == nil || dest == nil {
        return errors.New("src/dest is nil. You cannot insert to a nil map")
    }
    for key, value := range src {
        if reflect.TypeOf(value).String() != jsonType {
            (*dest)[key] = value
        } else {
            (*dest)[key] = make(map[string]int)
//Suspect code below causes the error.
            deepCopyJSON(value.(map[string]interface{}), &(((*dest)[key]).(map[string]interface{})))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The Error: cannot take the address of (*dest)[key].(map[string]interface {})
How do I get around this? Are there other ways to deep maps?

I primer on the internals of map in golang, will also be useful.

Comment: There's no need to pass `dest` as a pointer since you're just setting entries in the map. I'm confused by `((*dest)[key]).(map[string]interface{})`, though. You just set that to a `map[string]int`, so a type assertion to `map[string]interface{}` will fail. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @AndySchweig when I don't type assert I get the following error `cannot use &(*dest)[key] (type *interface {}) as type *map[string]interface {} in argument to deepCopyJSON`

Comment: Type asserting might avert that compiler error, but the assertion will fail at runtime because that value is a `map[string]int`.

Comment: @AndySchweig even with the assertion removed it does not compile. The error is the same as the orginal error plus the type error. `# cncli/client
../client/util.go:44:49: cannot take the address of (*dest)[key]
../client/util.go:44:49: cannot use &(*dest)[key] (type *interface {}) as type *map[string]interface {} in argument to deepCopyJSON
`

Comment: You have two problems. You can't take the address of a type assertion, and the type assertion won't work anyway. First of all, don't pass that map as a pointer. As I mentioned before, it isn't necessary. But there's a more fundamental problem, which is that you're creating a `map[string]int` and the function expects a `map[string]interface{}`. Those are different types. Why is the element type `int`? Shouldn't it be `interface{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func deepCopyJSON(src map[string]interface{}, dest map[string]interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        return errors.New("src is nil. You cannot read from a nil map")
    }
    if dest == nil {
        return errors.New("dest is nil. You cannot insert to a nil map")
    }
    jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &dest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think of 2 solutions.

1) Simply mashal it back, then copy the bytes.

2) Recursive calls as below.

```
func deepCopyJSON(src map[string]interface{}, dest map[string]interface{}) {
    for key, value := range src {
        switch src[key].(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            dest[key] = map[string]interface{}{}
            deepCopyJSON(src[key].(map[string]interface{}), dest[key].(map[string]interface{}))
        default:
            dest[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l6W1PD4lppG